# Electrical and thermal conductivity of graphite

Tags: solid-state-chemistry, conductivity, carbon-family, thermal-conductivity

I was reading about carbon family where it was mentioned that electrical conductivity of graphite increases with temperature while thermal conductivity decreases.

However, I could not find a suitable explanation for that. According to me, electrical conductivity should decrease with rise in temperature as it happens in case of conductors.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Graphite is not a typical conductor. In a way, it is related to semiconductors.

Comment: It is a very non-linear effect. The conductivity increases in a certain range but above 100 °C it starts to decrease. I don't think there is any rock solid explanation. See https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01135029

Comment: The mechanisms of heat and electrical conduction are different. Heat conductivity is encouraged by collective motions (phonons) that may become increasingly incoherent at high T. Electrical conductivity is harder to explain. Presumably pi electron delocalization is important, but why this should show a significant T dependence is not clear to me. A quick search suggests conductivity goes through a maximum with increasing T. Can you produce some references or specific temperature intervals?

Comment: My book does not mention any intervals.However ,from the above answers I understood that it depends upon the temperature intervals we are talking about.

Comment: I don't understand your heat conductivity explanation(I don't know quantum mechanics ).Can you simplify ?

Comment: Heat transmission in solids may be the result of collective vibrational motions which convey kinetic energy from one part of a lattice to another (analogous to waves in a body of water). Phonons are collective motions in the lattice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon